# Google Scholar: How to search by author's email?

Tags: google-scholar

I want to search for paper come from Google, Airbnb and Bytedance etc. (to learn about their machine learning application).

If I search for Airbnb.com, the result would look like this

[image]

Some are what I want, but some just mention airbnb.com in title or in content.

How can I restrcit `airbnb` to email address from authors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

See my answer to a related question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/121591/17254). Basically, Google (and seemingly also Google Scholar) appears to strip the at sign from the search query.

Unfortunately, I think this means Google Scholar is the wrong tool for this kind of search. Some of the better paywalled databases (such as [Web of Science](https://www.webofknowledge.com) or [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com)) allow filtering by affiliation. You can check with your university librarians what resources you have access to.