# Searching for specific characters in publication titles

Tags: google-scholar, literature-search, pubmed

Is there any way to search for articles that include a specific character in their name? For instance, suppose you want to find articles that include $, £ or € in their title.  When I have tried to search for such characters in [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) or [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com), I fail to get any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google Scholar I believe it depends on which character you're after - regular letters are fine, but certain special characters (like $, @, and punctuation marks) are stripped from the submitted search query, and won't work. That is, that's the case for the regular Google, and while I haven't found official documentation stating this, as far as I can tell, Google Scholar has the same behavior.

PubMed replaces certain special characters (such as $) with spaces. See [this help section](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3827/#pubmedhelp.PubMed_Character_Conversions).

For more reading, see these related questions on StackOverflow:

1. [How can I use a search engine to search for special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685615/7492468)
2. [Looking for special characters in Google](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842478/7492468)

Comment: This was a very helpful answer. Thank you. Do you know of any other search service where such a query would be possible?

Comment: @Phil I don't know of one, but I haven't tried them all. Unfortunately, it's often useful to remove these special characters (or reserve them for special use) - except when it isn't, so most services probably do. Web of Science treats $ as a [wildcard](https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/hs_wildcards.html), by the way.